# Limit of $\prod\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, products, infinite-product

Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\times \frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\times \cdots \times\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$$
No idea how to even start.

Comment: It's natural to start from factorization of the multipliers. Then you'll see some reduction.

Comment: Any hints with regard to this factorization?

Comment: $a^3\pm1=(a\pm1)(a^2\mp a+1)$.

Comment: still can't see a reduction

Comment: One more hint: $(n)+1=(n+2)-1$, $(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1=n^2+n+1$.

Comment: thus i have the following fraction $\frac{((2^3-2)+1)((2^3+1)^2-(2^3+1)+1)}{((2^3+2)-1)((2^3-1)^2+(2^3-1)+1)}$ that is still no reduction possible or maybe this will be simply -1?

Comment: Maybe take the logarithm. Then you have to sum a series.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the suggested factorizations,
and using

$\begin{array}\\
k^2-k+1
&=k(k-1)+1\\
&=(k-1+1)(k-1)+1\\
&=(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1\\
\end{array}
$

(this is really the key),

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_{k=2}^n \dfrac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}
&=\prod_{k=2}^n \dfrac{(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}{(k+1)(k^2-k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^n (k-1)}{\prod_{k=2}^n (k+1)}\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^n (k^2+k+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^n (k^2-k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^n (k-1)}{\prod_{k=2}^n (k+1)}\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^n (k^2+k+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^n ((k-1)^2+(k-1)+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k}{\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}k}\dfrac{\prod_{k=2}^n (k^2+k+1)}{ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (k^2+k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n(n+1)}\dfrac{n^2+n+1}{3}\\
&=\dfrac23\dfrac{ n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}\\
&=\dfrac23(1+\dfrac{ 1}{n^2+n})\\
& \to \dfrac23
\end{array}
$

Comment: Hello, why does it go from the fourth to the fifth equality, it is not clear to me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

An overkill. Since we have $$\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{k^{3}-1}{k^{3}+1}=\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{\left(k-1\right)\left(k^{2}+k+1\right)}{\left(k+1\right)\left(k^{2}-k+1\right)}=\prod_{k\geq2}\frac{\left(k-1\right)\left(k-\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k-\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\left(k+1\right)\left(k-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}$$ $$=\prod_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2-\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k+2-\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\left(k+3\right)\left(k+2-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k+2-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}
 $$ and recalling the identity $$\prod_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(k+a_{1}\right)\left(k+a_{2}\right)\left(k+a_{3}\right)}{\left(k+a_{4}\right)\left(k+a_{5}\right)\left(k+a_{6}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(a_{4}\right)\Gamma\left(a_{5}\right)\Gamma\left(a_{6}\right)}{\Gamma\left(a_{1}\right)\Gamma\left(a_{2}\right)\Gamma\left(a_{3}\right)},\, a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}=a_{4}+a_{5}+a_{6}
 $$ which follows from the [Euler's definition of the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions), we get $$P=\prod_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(k+1\right)\left(k+2-\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k+2-\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\left(k+3\right)\left(k+2-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(k+2-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(3\right)\Gamma\left(2-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1\right)\Gamma\left(2-\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2-\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}
 $$ and since $\Gamma\left(x+1\right)=x\Gamma\left(x\right)
 $ we get $$P=\frac{2}{\left(2-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(2-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{3}}.$$