# Let $P_n=\frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\times\frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\times\frac{4^3-1}{4^3+1}\times.....\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}.$Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$

Tags: limits

Let $P_n=\frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\times\frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\times\frac{4^3-1}{4^3+1}\times.....\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}.$Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$.

---

Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$
$\log L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log P_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log \frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}+\log\frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}+....+\log\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$

But here i am stuck and there is no way seeming to get the answer.Please help me.

Comment: Why would you expect this to have a nice answer?

Comment: Its answer is given to be $\frac{2}{3}$ in the book.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009566/the-limit-of-products-of-the-form-n3-1-n31

Comment: Hint: $a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$ and $a^3+1=(a+1)(a^2-a+1)$